# ¿Como crear una condición según sea un archivo o un directorio?

Tags: condiciones, powershell

Necesito crear una condición verificando si la variable que le paso es un **archivo** o un **directorio** tal que así:

```
if ($variable -eq "directorio")
{
    Haz esto
}
else
{
    Haz esto otro
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar *Get-Item*, este retornara el tipo de archivo con el que estas tratando, en este caso si fuera un *.txt* seria algo como esto:

```
 $variable="archivo.txt"

 if((Get-Item $variable) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){
     echo "Directorio"
 } elseif((Get-Item $variable) -is [System.IO.FileInfo]){
     echo "Archivo"
 }
```

Mas informacion [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)